# Loop thru rows that contain file names and copy info into those files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master file that contains rows of data that I want to copy to multiple files based on the file name in column I.
So if the master file rows 2-4 have the same file name in col I, copy all data in columns A-H into a file. Then move down the spreadsheet, rows 5-10 have the same file name copy columns A-H. The data should be pasted after the last row of data.

I have code that opens the files correctly, but it is not going thru each row as expected. I have been testing just with Firstname that is in Col B

```
Sub Copy_Into_Files()

    Dim Date, FirstName, LastName, City  As String
    Dim SourceSheet, DestSheet As Worksheet
    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i, erow As Integer
    Dim CopyTo As Workbook
    Dim FileNames As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        FileNames = .Range("I2:I" & lr).Value
    End With
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If FileNames(i, 1) Like "*.xlsx" Then
            Set CopyTo = Workbooks.Open(FileNames(i, 1), _
                                           ReadOnly:=False, _
                                           Password:="")

           With CopyTo
            FirstName = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
            Set DestSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
            erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 2).Value = FirstName
            MsgBox FirstName
           End With
        End If
        Set CopyTo = Nothing
    Next i
 End Sub
```

The code appears to be copying one instance of the firstname correctly, but not moving thru all the rows that match the filename

Comment: Search for master file - I have a question about this with answer...

Comment: `FileNames = .Range("I2:I" & lr).Value` is not working neither as array (no declaration) or Range (should be assigned with set), so which one is your idea with FileNames?

Comment: @Solar Mike, please place a link to your answer, not a searching

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego not easy on a smart phone... but if you understood you could look at the (few) questions I have posted and find it that way.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego The search function is **so** useful on here - I have found many solutions to my issues without having to post and cause duplicate questions...

Comment: The first element in FileNames (`FileNames(1,1)` )comes from I2, so your code skips over this element completely, since your `i` loop counter starts at 2.  Also, `On Error Resume Next` will only hide any errors which occur - if this is used it should only be as narrow in scope as is required - it's not a solution which should be set for the whole method.  Also need to call Close on each file you open - setting `CopyTo` to `Nothing` doesn't close the file.

Comment: None of the lines in your `With` block actually refer to that block's scope.

Comment: Also declaration of your variables is not correct - first of all You are trying to declare 'Date' which is not proper name for var, second of all every var needs its type in VBA - instead of ' Dim SourceSheet, DestSheet As Worksheet' You should type ' Dim SourceSheet as Worksheet, DestSheet As Worksheet' etc